# So what exactly is RESERVE BATTERY LEVEL(IN %) in Dell ALIENWARE Laptop?

Tags: kernel, battery-life, system-reserved-partition

So what exactly is RESERVE BATTERY LEVEL(IN %) in Dell ALIENWARE Laptop?

**RESERVE BATTERY LEVEL (RBL)**

WHAT is **RESERVE BATTERY LEVEL**?
Please follow with the series of screenshots for explanation

Screenshot O1
**Link -** **https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC4mO.png**

The screenshot shows selection of given *% level* of the RBL.
The *% level* can be increased up to **100%**

Screenshot O2
**Link -** **https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIBCB.png**

The *% level* can be increased up to **100%**

And What is **RBL**?
Is RBL related to Battery Consumption? Or is a state to contain some battery charge for Critical Battery Situations?

Screenshot O3
**Link** - **https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsi1R.png**

A processor in a computer running Windows has two different modes: **USER MODE / KERNEL MODE**
The processor switches between the two modes depending on what type of code is running on the processor. Applications run in user mode, and core operating system components run in kernel mode. While many drivers run in kernel mode, some drivers may run in user mode.
*Source - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/user-mode-and-kernel-mode*

To understand this, I have created a **MONKEY - BANANA THEORY**

The **KERNAL** is a computer program at the core of a computer's operating system with complete control over everything in the system.
The code in memory files is always in running state, and we take Memory Files as **Bananas** and the KERNAL as **Monkey**.

As long as **Monkey** is eating **Bananas** - The Stomach of Monkey is working properly. Once the Bananas are not provided to the Monkey then his stomach gets really upset.
If the Monkey is fed Bananas in less time than the condition of Monkey is CRITICAL which means that the memory files being processed during a short duration will need some minimum amount of power supply to keep the Monkey**/ KERNEL** Critical Health Running.

The Bananas has its Weight (Protected area of memory) -

And what is **KERNEL Space**?
KERNEL Space is where the KERNEL executes and provides its services.
This Memory Space needs power supply to be under production,

Relation between Reserve Battery Level and System Crashes
Reserve Battery Level was created to avoid System Crashes.

A **System Crash** is the situation in which a program, either a user application or a part of the operating system, stops performing its expected function(s) and responding to other parts of the system. The program might appear to the user to freeze.
If such program is critical to the operation of the kernel, the entire computer could stall or shut down.
*Source - http://www.linfo.org/kernel.html*

What is I/O
Input/Output service is performed by the KERNEL.
I/O is any program, operation or device that transfers data to or from a CPU and to or from a peripheral device (Hard Disk).

Is **RESERVE BATTERY LEVEL** the Memory Space provided in the **KERNEL**?
But Why **% level** of RBL?

Screenshot O4
**Link -** **https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtXkR.png**

Why there is no proper information related to this Topic?
I suggest more understanding w.r.t RBL.

Strobe

Comment: You got a invalid value due to the 1000% value.  You can’t set a percentage value if the limit is 0% to 100%

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "Reserve Battery Level" in Windows perform any function besides the popup?](https://superuser.com/questions/1214726/does-reserve-battery-level-in-windows-perform-any-function-besides-the-popup)

Comment: Re your theory: electrical power is supplied to the CPU regardless of the processor mode (i.e. kernel or user mode).  The kernel can control power consumption if the system has power-management controller(s) (e.g. based on anticipated load), but it doesn't function like anything you described.

Answer (score 2):

Reserve battery level is quite simply a battery level where Windows will give you an alert that your battery is about to run out. It is very similar to the low battery level and the critical battery level. The only difference is that you can set the low battery level and the critical battery level to trigger power events such as standby or hibernation, whereas the reserve battery level only gives you a warning.

Generally (or at least the way I know it), the low battery is the highest level, for example 20%, the reserve battery level is the middle level, for example 10%, and the critical battery level is the lowest level, for example 5%. That way, you first get a warning at 20% (low battery), then again at 10% (reserve battery level - as in a reserve for you to wrap up what you're doing), and then at 5% you can set it to hibernate, for example. AFAIK, it has nothing to do with memory reserves or anything like that, and it definitely shouldn't have anything to do with system crashes (unless you have a faulty battery, but that's another can of worms and doesn't have anything to do with the reserve battery level).

In fact, you have the exact same options in the Windows power settings.

Comment: With this Screenshot Link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grm98.png       It clears that the  Reserve Battery Level RBL is a notification for the time provided to the user to save and prepare the system for Shutdown/Hibernate.

Comment: @Strobe +1 for the workaholic power plan :D